# copy files from windows 10 to ubuntu VMware ESXI

Tags: apt, server, package-management, windows, vmware

I create Ubuntu virtual machine on VMware ESXi and that machine haven't any connectivity to the network. I want to build a database server and an App server and to do that I have to install some packages.
Is there any way to install the packages without connecting to the network?

one of the methods I saw is to download the packages to my PC (which is Windows 10) and then transfer that packages to my Ubuntu VM, but I didn't have any idea how to do that as I am a beginner in Linux.

Any help please?

Comment: Your problem seems to be an ESXi setup problem, not Ubuntu problem. Did you create an Ubuntu VM without any network interfaces? If yes, add some network interface to it - you won't be able to use it as a server anyway if it doesn't have a network interface.
If the VM does have a network interface, you seem to have some network configuration issue on ESXi level, and you need to solve it there.